# Trying to do a simple calculation, results are incorrect

Tags: java, overloading

The assignment is "Write a class that has three overloaded static methods for calculating the areas of a circle, rectangle, cylinder." I'm having trouble with the cylinder. It recognizes pi when the area of a circle in being calculated so why not the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but the formula you use for the cylinder case gives the **volume** of the cylinder.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: Using `float` in the third method, just to distinguish it from the second method, is really bad. Give them different, more meaningful names. This is a bad use of overloading a method name.

Comment: I agree on 'bad' (I would reject this in a code review) but according to the OP the assignment demands use of overloading. So (if accurately reported to us) the requirements seem to be to distinguish two identically-named methods each of which needs two floating-point arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your two methods `area(float, double)` and `area(double, double)` are getting confused. In general, their signatures are so close that I would not recommend it.  There is no logical reason, for example, why the radius of a circle must be represented as a `double` but the radius of a cylinder is only required to the precision of a `float`.

What is the type of the variable that holds the radius of the cylinder? If you want to call the "cylinder" method then the radius **must** be `float` rather than `double`.

(And as I mentioned in a comment, your cylinder routine is computing volume, not area.  What do you mean by 'area' of a 3-D object anyway?  Surface area?  Including the 'ends' of the cylinder?)